# Invalid audience claim in token The JSON Web Token (JWT) used as a token does not have the correct audience. Ensure you are using the correct token

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, claims-based-identity

Unable to authenticate against a backend api using Azure. Error says invalid audience but the *aud* claim had the backend api client id when troubleshooting in *jwt.ms*.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the token analysis.

Comment: If you acquired an access token with the correct audience, then you most likely have an issue with your authentication configuration. Could you share that?

Comment: @CarlZhao that is very sensitive information i am afraid I can not share it.

Comment: How did you configure the authentication information?

Comment: @CarlZhao In the backend flask api i am using AzureResourceProtector to which we pass AZURE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_ID, AZURE_OAUTH_CLIENT_APPLICATION_IDS, AZURE_OAUTH_TENANCY config parameters along with the app object.

Frontend is a react app using react-aad-msal library which we are using to create MsalAuthProvider object with params auth :{authority, frontendclientId, redirectUri} , scope:[api://{backendapiclientid}/DefaultAppAccess] ,LoginType.Redirect.

Comment: @juunas please check above config information. Also I checked the token generated by frontend in jwt.ms which decodes to claim aud: backendapiclientid.

Comment: @Niru  Which authentication flow do you use to obtain an access token?

Comment: @CarlZhao I am using OAuth2 for resource protections and OpenID for SSO integration.

Comment: @Niru  Have you added the client application to the api application?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHw1E.png

Answer (score 3):

From your error report, it is indeed a 401 error, that is, your audience does not match the api you want to call, but your parsing token `aud` claims to have the backend api client ID, so I think your authentication There may be a problem with the configuration, I use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to do a simple demonstration for you:

[image]

Next,under 'API permissions', give your front-end application access to your backend api:

- Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the 'My APIs' tab.
- Find your backend application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant admin consent for your APIs.

[image]

Get token:

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I am a developer for the front end application and I have access to the frontend and backend configs right now. Is it possible that these configs reflect in the manifest of azure portal ? If so please provide a sample manifest of the backend api client so that I could get it compared with my backend application with the help of my Azure admin. @CarlZhao

Comment: @Niru  Sorry, my api application list contains some private information that is not convenient to provide. Have you configured your front-end and back-end applications according to the process in my answer?

Comment: yes I have configured it as described above.The directions you have given above are specific to azure portal so couldn't try much of you suggested. Nevertheless, Thank you for the guidance.